# Child div elements that auto-columises based on 100% parent height

Tags: css

I have numerous div elements that I would like to be scrolled horitonzaly rather than vertically, based on 100% parent height.

I have done a quick move up of the desired result.

As an example if the parent is 600 pixels tall, six 100px items will fit before it makes a new column and a 900px height would fit 9 items.

How can I achieve this affect? I only need it to work in Chrome is cross-browser support is not available for this.

Code for you to fiddle with, http://jsfiddle.net/yQ5AR/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
    <div class="item">13</div>
    <div class="item">14</div>
    <div class="item">15</div>
    <div class="item">16</div>
    <div class="item">17</div>
    <div class="item">18</div>
    <div class="item">19</div>
    <div class="item">20</div>
</div>

.container{
    max-height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.item{
    height: 100px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you mean the layout must change as the browser resizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox for this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yQ5AR/2/)**

### CSS

```
.container{
    max-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item{
      height: 70px;
      background: silver;
      width: 200px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS `columns` and  `column-break-inside` should do what you're looking for (`-webkit` in this case since you only care about Chrome).

http://jsfiddle.net/yQ5AR/4/

### CSS

```
.container{
    max-height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-columns: 100px;
}

.item{
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```