# How to wrap a div vertically and then horizontally

Tags: jquery, css

I need to show the search result data in my site horizontally. I follow a metro UI approach for my website, so I want the data to flow horizontally instead of vertically.

What I require is demonstrated in the below image:

[image: Desired OutPut]

The resulted data is dynamic. I want to draw the divs vertically first based on the parent div height and then horizontally. Something similar to WPF wrap panel, but I haven't been able to achieve it yet.

This is what I have tried, drawing horizontally and then vertically:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/4wuJz/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div id="wrap1">
       <div class="result">
           <div class="title">1</div>
           <div class="postcontent">  
              <p>Test</p>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="result">
           <div class="title">2</div>
           <div class="postcontent">
              <p>Test</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
   width:100%;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   overflow:scroll;
   overflow-y:hidden;
}

#wrap1 {
   width:2500px;
   height:500px;
   text-align: center;
}


.result {
   width: 300px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   float:left;
   background: rgba(120,30,20,0.5);
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 30px 0px 30px 30px; 
}
```

How can I change my code so that I meet the desired output? Any jQuery plugins available for this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/20734869/703717

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `clear: left` to the `.result` class so your boxes are stacked vertically.

Then wrap results in blocks of 3 and float these blocks horizontally. You can do that logic with whichever back-end language you may be using to output the results markup or with jQuery:

```
$('.result:nth-child(3n+1)').each(function() {
    $(this).add( $(this).next().next().addBack() ).wrapAll('<div style="float:left"></div>');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4wuJz/10/)

---

Here's a more responsive solution which re-calculates on window resize: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4wuJz/12/).

Note: it assumes all boxes have the same height. You can hardcode a `max-height` in the `resultHeight` variable if that's not the case.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var resultHeight = $('.result:first').outerHeight(true),
        nRows = Math.floor( $('#wrap1').height() / resultHeight );

    $('.results-column').contents().unwrap();
    $('.result:nth-child('+nRows+'n+1)').each(function() {
        $(this).nextAll().slice(0, nRows-1).add(this).wrapAll('<div class="results-column"></div>');
    });
}).resize();
```

Added CSS:

```
#wrap1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.results-column {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

---

Also check out [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-complete.html) with its `cellsByColumn`/`fitColumns` layouts.

---

And lastly, your use case is a prime example for the use of the [Flexible Box Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/). I haven't mentioned this yet because there are already other answers showing this solution, and also because it is rather hard to make cross-browser at the moment:

- Firefox <= 27, IE10 and Safari <= 6 support an old version of the spec
- Newer Chrome, Safari and IE11 support the new syntax
- Can't forget all the browser prefixes!

Reference: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Though, all is not lost yet. If you want to use Flexbox today, there's a very useful [Flexbox generator](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/).

CSS-only solution using Flexbox: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4wuJz/13/)

```
#wrap1 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

I've tested this solution and it works correctly in IE10, IE11, Chrome 31, Opera 18 and Firefox 29 Nightly.

**Note:** Firefox <= 27 does not support Flexbox with more than one row/column (it does not support `flex-wrap: wrap`). I've tested this on Firefox 29 (nightly) and it works correctly, so I believe it should land on stable soon enough.

Comment: Seems like a very good approach. Will try it out. the only overhead is i need to change the logic each time window is resized.

Comment: You mean, changing the number of vertical boxes to fit in the viewport?

Comment: @Moniecorleone updated. `=]` I haven't used Isotope yet but it seems to do exactly what you want, I've added it to the answer as well.

Comment: No problem, I've also added a flexbox alternative for the sake of completeness (should note that it has no IE<=9 support, and is buggy in Firefox<=27 due to its lack of `wrap` support).

Comment: +1 Good answer =) Balanced approach to an `.js` and `non-js` solution, especially as the flex fills in the gaps where the others had started on.

Answer (score 6):

Flexbox will be a JavaScript-less solution:

```css
#wrap1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4wuJz/5/

Comment: Very interesting +1, may I ask the cross browser compatibility for this?

Comment: Flexbox makes everything too easy. `;)` +1 though [support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) should be noted.

Comment: @MackieeE see the link in Fabricio's comment. When possible, always refer to CanIUse, it's the most accurate and up-to-date reference on the web.

Comment: Works Good in chrome. But not on safari and firefox. Although my targeted browser is chrome, i cant use this approach since i may support multiple browsers in future :(

Comment: Firefox and Safari support Flexbox but you need some prefixes and a different syntax.

Comment: I would add  align-content:start; to stack all items together.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the CSS columns, without changing much of your code:

```
div.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;    
    -webkit-column-width: 100px; 
       -moz-column-width: 100px; 
            column-width: 100px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 16px;
       -moz-column-gap: 16px;
            column-gap: 16px;
}
```

Check this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/Be9B3/**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `display:flex`

Check the forked codepen demo: http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/zolcF

Read more [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-height:600px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;

  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```